# What is the proper way to move view according to UISlider position in swift?

Tags: swift, view, slider, move

I have a vertical view and vertical slider on screen next to each other. They have almost same size. I want this view to move according to position of slider. I was trying this way:

```
if oldValue < Int(sender.value) {
        viewToMoveTopYConstreint.constant = viewToMoveTopYConstreint.constant - heightOfMovement
        oldValue = Int(sender.value)
    } else if oldValue > Int(sender.value) {
        viewToMoveTopYConstreint.constant = viewToMoveTopYConstreint.constant + heightOfMovement
        oldValue = Int(sender.value)
    }
```

heightOfMovement is value to move my view for – e.g. 5 points

If I move slider slowly, view moves pretty accurate, but if I do it quickly, view moves in the way, like I only changed one value instead of twenty.

I know I can try to do it with "for in", but I was wondering is there a more proficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you don't use the sliders `value` property, but instead only add some `heightOfMovement` (nobody except you knows where this value comes from).

I think the following would be more straight-forward:

- rename `viewToMoveTopYConstreint` to `viewToMoveTopYConstraint` (just a spelling mistake :-)
- set the `minValue` of the slider to `0`
- set the `maxValue` of the slider to the height of the view to be moved
- in your `@IBAction` just do the following:

```
    viewToMoveTopYConstraint.constant = sender.value
```